# match two text value columns if equals put one of them in new column R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data Frame

```
`Person Class1 Class2 Class3
  Joe       A      A      A
  Joe       A      C      C
  Fred      B      B      B
  Jane      D      C      A
  Fred      F      7      F
  Jane      B      E      A
   R      <NA>     C      C
   S      <NA>     4      4 `
```

I will add a new column if the value in Class1 Match Class2 or Class3 the result like

```
`  Person Class1 Class2 Class3 Match1
   Joe      A      A      A     A
   Joe      A      C      C     A
  Fred      B      B      B     B
  Jane      D      C      A     D
  Fred      F      C      F     F
  Jane      B      E      A     B
    R     <NA>     C      C     C
    S     <NA>     E      E     E
```

I try `df1$Match1 <- ifelse(match(df1$Class1,df1$Class2),df1$Class1, df1$Class2)`
but I get numbers ..

can any one help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Match1 := do.call(fcoalesce, .SD), .SDcols = patterns('^Class')]
```

-output

```
df1
#   Person Class1 Class2 Class3 Match1
#1:    Joe      A      A      A      A
#2:    Joe      A      C      C      A
#3:   Fred      B      B      B      B
#4:   Jane      D      C      A      D
#5:   Fred      F      7      F      F
#6:   Jane      B      E      A      B
#7:      R   <NA>      C      C      C
#8:      S   <NA>      4      4      4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person = c("Joe", "Joe", "Fred", "Jane", "Fred", 
"Jane", "R", "S"), Class1 = c("A", "A", "B", "D", "F", "B", NA, 
NA), Class2 = c("A", "C", "B", "C", "7", "E", "C", "4"), Class3 = c("A", 
"C", "B", "A", "F", "A", "C", "4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` to get first non-NA value in `'Class'` columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(Match1 = coalesce(!!! select(., starts_with('Class'))))
df2
```

Comment: but when I change the Na with the value of class2 must be ifelse or is.na right?

Comment: This selects first non-NA value in Class columns. So it will select `Class1` if it is not NA, `Class2` if `Class1` is `NA` and so on.